# Python processing nested json

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am feeding the following data to my python script as an argument:

```
source=Blabla||
name=TEST Error in Log - Error: 3345||
item_value={ "Error": 3345, "Message": "Some error occurred", "Status": 1 }
```

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, json 
data=sys.argv[3]
if 'NOTE: Escalation cancelled' in data:
        exit(0)
data=data.split('||')
datadictionary = {}
for item in data:
        key, val = item.split("=", 1)
        k=key.strip()
        v=(((((val.strip())).replace('\n',"<br>")).replace("`", "&lsquo")))
        datadictionary[ k ] = v

datajson = json.dumps(datadictionary)
datajson=datajson.encode('utf8')

print(datajson)
```

It gives the following output:

```
{"source": "Blabla", "name": "TEST Error in Log - Error: 3345", "item_value": "{ \"Error\": 3345, \"Message\": \"Some error occurred\", \"Status\": 1 }"}
```

Which is not a proper JSON as item_value is a string rather than a JSON object. How can I generate a nested JSON here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I need to first decode the JSON object first by the following line:

```
datadictionary['item_value']=json.loads(datadictionary['item_value'])
```

So the script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, json
data=sys.argv[3]
if 'NOTE: Escalation cancelled' in data:
        exit(0)
data=data.split('||')
datadictionary = {}
for item in data:
        key, val = item.split("=", 1)
        k=key.strip()
        v=val.strip().replace('\n',"<br>").replace("`", "&lsquo")
        datadictionary[ k ] = v

datadictionary['item_value']=json.loads(datadictionary['item_value'])
datajson = json.dumps(datadictionary)
datajson=datajson.encode('utf8')


print(datajson)
```

And the output:

```
{"source": "Blabla", "name": "TEST Error in Log - Error: 3345", "item_value": {"Status": 1, "Message": "Some error occurred", "Error": 3345}}
```